# How to simulate power outage for a single NUT client?

Tags: test, ups, nut

I've changed the behaviour of a single server (configured as `netclient`) when on UPS, but I'm not sure how to test it in isolation. [dummy-ups](http://www.networkupstools.org/docs/man/dummy-ups.html) seems related, but even the configuration looks completely different from the `nut.conf` I have inherited. Does anyone have an example of doing this?